# UIAlertController - iOS 8 - iPad - Not Centering Properly

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to display a UIAlertController with some action buttons. It works fine on the iPhone, because it pops from the bottom of the device. I have a problem with the ipad, the UIAlertController does not center properly. It shows a bit off to the right. I can subtract from the x coordinate by subtracting say 150f. Is there a way to just get it center?

```
   UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                             message:@"Select your Choice"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];


[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:cancel];



view.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
view.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
[self presentViewController: view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is `self.view.frame` relative to `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`? Is it perfectly centred?

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple actions then better to use `Alertstyle`, it centers automatically or if you insist to use `Actionsheet` style, try setting `popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0` this works nice with a fixed orientation but fails if you rotate in iPad.

```
// Alert
- (void) showAlert
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TEst" message:@"test Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```